# Windows freezes when using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, freeze, shortcuts

I have a relatively small question about Windows [I'm using XP, but this question is probably not version-related] OS, for which I haven't found solution in any search engine. The problem is:

I have keyboard shortcuts assigned to some applications, such as Notepad: `[Ctrl] + [Alt] + [M]` and Calculator: `[Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Q]`. When I use any of them, OS freezes for about 10-20 seconds and then quickly replays all of the actions I've made during that pause [any `[Alt] + [Tab]`, clicks on the taskbar and so on] and opens desired program.

What causes such behavior and how can I force Windows to resolve my shortcuts without such delay?

Comment: How are you assigning the shortcuts?

Comment: Executable's "properties", there is a field you can use.

Comment: From [Jorge Tuero](http://superuser.com/users/221607/jorge-tuero): I've been having this very same issue with the Ctrl+Shift combo. So it's not esxclusive to the Ctrl+Alt combination

Comment: In Windows 7, this issue can be reproduced by suspending a process (e.g. using PsSuspend), then triggering the shortcut. Explorer will hang until the process is resumed. It seems to want to wait for a response, why I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Why Ctrl+Alt shouldn't be used as a shortcut modifier](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040329-00/?p=40003) :

> You may have noticed that Windows
> doesn't use Ctrl+Alt as a keyboard
> shortcut anywhere. (Or at least it
> shouldn't.) If a chorded modifier is
> needed, it's usually Ctrl+Shift.
>
> That's because Ctrl+Alt has special
> meaning on many keyboards. The
> combination Ctrl+Alt is also known as
> AltGr, and it acts as an alternate
> shift key.
>
> Most international keyboards remap the
> right-hand Alt key to act as AltGr, so
> instead of the finger-contorting
> Ctrl+Alt+Q, you can usually type
> RAlt+Q.
>
> Sometimes a program accidentally uses
> Ctrl+Alt as a shortcut modifier and
> they get bug reports like, "Every time
> I type the letter 'đ', the program
> thinks I want to start a mailmerge."

Comment: Ok, but I do want to know what Windows is doing when i type [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Something] and why is it freezing - it is not freezing when I do [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Del]. Not using that combination is not a solution because it does not solve the problem - only makes it working for some time.

Comment: What it's doing is specific to the keyboard and Windows version. It may be launching some program, which in this case can be detected using Process Explorer of sysinternals (with slow View/Update speed). But I don't understand why you think using another combination than Ctrl-Alt will only make it work for some time.

Comment: Ok, I understand that [Ctrl] + [Alt] may be wrong choice, but I'm at war with this problem for a long time so I want to know what causes it and how to fix that behavior, even if I switch to other combination.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in my environment, so can't help. But you might even have come up against an undocumented "feature" in your Windows version.